# PHP 5.4 session issue

Tags: php, session

I'm working locally with PHP v5.3.13 and have this simple login page:

```
session_start();
include_once('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_username = $_POST['username'];
    $_password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $auth = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM admin WHERE username='$_username'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($auth);

    if(($row['username']==$_username) && ($row['password']==$_password)){
        $_SESSION['logged'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
        $_SESSION['loggedAt']= time();
        header("location:dashboard.php");
    }else{
        header("location:login.php");
    }
}
```

All working good locally, but after upload them into server, login just give me blank page and not direct me to dashboard page. I've check it, my hosting just upgrade to PHP 5.4

Also try to google some help, I just don't understand where to start =p

Anyone can help?

Comment: Start with error logs.

Comment: Turn error reporting on with: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` And check the error logs! Also make sure all files are located at the right place! (`connect.php`, `dashboard.php`, `login.php`) (BTW: wouldn't use `md5` and `mysql_`)

Comment: @zerkms I don't see any error, it just not direct the page.

Comment: `I just don't understand where to start` thats the thought of a child. No offense. Programming is not only getting the code, it's also about debugging. So as @Zerkms said, start with your error log. (its a file stored on your server in the folder where the file of your login should be) Start building in checks and error outputs. It helps you debugging so much easier.

Comment: I think issue with `mysql_*`. please check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: @zerkms Okay, I got this: Notice: Undefined variable: signinError
solanki mysql fine and working good

Comment: @Mikael: what would be your next step? You know a error message. So?

Comment: @Mikael so you have to set the variable appearantly! ;) maybe its handy to define it ;)

Comment: @Mikael Try to build in some `checkpoint's` like if the connection fails or if the query fails and so on

Comment: @zerkms After login, on the other pages, I just get empty session variable

Comment: I got this from error log: [01-Dec-2014 12:59:07 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the stern yet best answer is to... delete that piece of code and copy an authentication function from a working example made by somebody with good experience in log in forms.

In fact, in those few lines:

1. You are using code which can be immensely injected and exploited to breach in your website.
2. Does not help you are using utterly obvious table name and field names. Any script newbie may guess them and use point 1 above for even more damage.
3. From your code is pretty obvious you are implementing access to all including your admin users. With such weak code, the first to be breached will indeed be your admin credentials.
4. Cherry on the cake: even if your script had been industry standard made, I'd suggest you to salt the passwords, not just to MD5 them.

Please home brew your code - that's how you really learn - but use the authentication code made by someone experienced. That'll allow you to survive to tomorrow and improve your writing.